# Erro a não conseguir aceder à coleção de imagens C#

Tags: c#, .net, imagemagick

Estou utilizado o Magick.NET para poder escolher a compresão JPEG para os meus ficheiros TIFF. Assim, guardo cada um com essa compressão numa coleção de imagens. Por fim quero juntar todos os TIFF da coleção num só ficheiro.

Mas quando faço "images.Combine();" recebo o erro:

[image: Erro]

Também tentei fazer a mesma ação sem a linha de código mencionada acima mas recebo o mesmo erro. No entanto, não vejo onde o objeto foi `Disposed` pois está tudo dentro de um bloco `using`.

### Código:

```
public void JoinTiffJPEG(string[] imageFiles, string outFile)
{
    using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
    {        
        try
        {
            MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
            settings.Compression = CompressionMethod.JPEG;
            for (int i = 0; i <= (imageFiles.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                using (var image = new MagickImage(File.ReadAllBytes(imageFiles[i]), settings))
                {
                    image.Settings.Compression = CompressionMethod.JPEG;
                    // Add the image
                    images.Add(image);
                }
            }
            images.Combine();
            Stream output = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create);
            images.Write(output, MagickFormat.Tif);

            //images.Dispose();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Deita fora o `using`, na linha `using (var image = ...)`.

Comment: @MarceloShinitiUchimura  Era isso, obrigada! No entanto, o ficheiro afinal só tem a primeira página e não todas... Consegue me ajuda nisso ou devo postar uma nova questão?

Comment: Nova questão, por favor.

Comment: Certo. Obrigada.

Comment: @MarceloShinitiUchimura Coloque isso na resposta, por favor. E Sofia, quando houver a resposta, marque como resolvido por favor. :) Isso pode ajudar os próximos a terem a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Certo, eu fá-lo-ei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com ajuda do comentário de @MarceloShinitiUchimura , a resposta é retirar o bloco **using** na linha

```
using (var image = new MagickImage(File.ReadAllBytes(imageFiles[i]), settings))
```

Sendo assim, o código final ficará:

```
    public void JoinTiffJPEG(string[] imageFiles, string outFile)
    {
        using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
        {

            try
            {
                MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
                settings.Compression = CompressionMethod.JPEG;

                for (int i = 0; i <= (imageFiles.Length - 1); i++)
                {
                    MagickImage image = new MagickImage(File.ReadAllBytes(imageFiles[i]), settings);
                    image.Settings.Compression = CompressionMethod.JPEG;
                    // Add the image
                    images.Add(image);

                }
                images.Combine();
                Stream output = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create);
                images.Write(output, MagickFormat.Tif);

                //images.Dispose();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }
    }
```