# Combinar ficheiros TIFF em C#

Tags: c#, .net, imagemagick

Estou a tentar combinar vários ficheiros TIFF num multipage. 
Estou utilizado Magick.NET mas o resultado final é um TIFF com apenas a primeira página.

Testei com um ficheiro com 10 páginas mas apenas ficou com uma. Penso que haja algum problema com a linha "images.Combine()" mas não tenho a certeza. Assim, o que tenho que muda no código para que combine os ficheiros de forma correta?

### Código:

```
    public void JoinTiffJPEG(string[] imageFiles, string outFile)
    {
        using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
        {

            try
            {
                MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
                settings.Compression = CompressionMethod.JPEG;

                for (int i = 0; i <= (imageFiles.Length - 1); i++)
                {
                    MagickImage image = new MagickImage(File.ReadAllBytes(imageFiles[i]), settings);
                    image.Settings.Compression = CompressionMethod.JPEG;
                    // Add the image
                    images.Add(image);

                }
                images.Combine();
                Stream output = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create);
                images.Write(output, MagickFormat.Tif);

                //images.Dispose();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }
    }
```

Este é o conteúdo da MagickImageCollection depois de guardar as 10 páginas do ficheiro:
[image: Coleção de imagens]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Juntar vários ficheiros TIFF num só em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/380804/juntar-v%c3%a1rios-ficheiros-tiff-num-s%c3%b3-em-c)

Comment: @rnd_rss Fui eu que publiquei ambas e são questões diferentes. Leia ambas ;)  Esta é sobre o ato de juntar os TIFFs e na outra era porque dava erro numa linha de código.

Comment: Você debugou o código?

Comment: Sim @LeandroAngelo e a `MagickImageCollection images` fica de facto com as imagens lá, mas quando guardo e faço "Write" ele não guarda todas as páginas.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo adicionei uma imagem do debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de colocar a [questão](https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=35954&p=165837#p165837) também no site de suporte do Magick.NET e com a ajuda de @LucasMiranda , cheguei à conclusão que a solução é mais simples do que isso.

Assim, o código fica:

```
public void JoinTiffJPEG(string[] imageFiles, string outFile)
{
    using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
    {

        try
        {
            MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
            settings.Compression = CompressionMethod.JPEG;
            for (int i = 0; i <= (imageFiles.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                MagickImage image = new MagickImage(File.ReadAllBytes(imageFiles[i]), settings);
                image.Settings.Compression = CompressionMethod.JPEG;
                // Add the image
                images.Add(image);
            }
            images.Write(outFile); 
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O que você está esquecendo é que o método merge() e o combine() retornam uma imagem, e você não está atribuindo em lugar algum, seria essa imagem que você deveria escrever para obter o resultado combinado, segue abaixo:

```
public void JoinTiffJPEG(string[] imageFiles, string outFile)
    {
        using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
        {

            try
            {
                MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
                settings.Compression = CompressionMethod.JPEG;

                for (int i = 0; i <= (imageFiles.Length - 1); i++)
                {
                    MagickImage image = new MagickImage(File.ReadAllBytes(imageFiles[i]), settings);
                    image.Settings.Compression = CompressionMethod.JPEG;
                    // Add the image
                    images.Add(image);

                }
                var imagemCombinada = images.Combine();  //atribuição do resultado
                Stream output = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create);
                imagemCombinada.Write(output, MagickFormat.Tif); //escrevendo resultado combinado

                //images.Dispose();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }
    }
```

--Atualização, caso você queira combiná-las uma abaixo da outra ou lado a lado o comando que você está buscando é AppendHorizontally e AppendVertically, exemplo:

```
public void JoinTiffJPEG(string[] imageFiles, string outFile)
        {
            using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
            {

                try
                {
                    MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
                    settings.Compression = CompressionMethod.JPEG;

                    for (int i = 0; i <= (imageFiles.Length - 1); i++)
                    {
                        MagickImage image = new MagickImage(File.ReadAllBytes(imageFiles[i]), settings);
                        image.Settings.Compression = CompressionMethod.JPEG;
                        // Add the image
                        images.Add(image);

                    }
                    var imagemCombinadaNaVertical = images.AppendVertically();  //atribuição do resultado
                    Stream output = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create);
                    imagemCombinadaNaVertical .Write(output, MagickFormat.Tif); //escrevendo resultado combinado

                    //images.Dispose();
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta @LucasMiranda , mas o resultado deu uma imagem sobreposta com outras... veja aqui: https://ibb.co/SvYRCkJ

Comment: entendi, você quer que elas fiquem uma abaixo da outra é isso?

Comment: Certo @LucasMiranda , quero que fique um TIFF multipage, por exemplo, eu estou a converter um PDF para TIFF e esse PDF tem 10 páginas, então TIFF vai ficar com 10 páginas também, mas com a compressão JPEG.